# Trying to move a file and add a date timestamp

Tags: date, vbscript, file-move

Been reading through some of the questions and answers last couple days and can't work out where I'm going wrong here I would appreciate any help given. So I'm trying to move a file to a different fold before pulling in a new copy but I want the one I'm moving to have a Date timestamp after (just so I have a record of it in future). Apologies if this is a bit rough its my second time trying to do something like this.

```
DIM Date1

Date1 = Now()
DIM FSO 
SET FSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


FSO.Movefile "I:\This is it\External Storage\Replen\Data\LOCATIONS\*ITEM INVENTORY BY PURCHASE ORDER.csv*", "I:\This is it\External Storage\Replen\Data\LOCATIONS\ITEM INVENTORY BY PURCHASE ORDER\" & Date1.csv

With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

.MoveFile "C:\Users\s.c\Downloads\*.csv*", "I:\This is it\External Storage\Replen\Data\LOCATIONS\"
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will move the `sSourceFile` (`ITEM INVENTORY BY PURCHASE ORDER.csv` in your case) to `sDestinationFolder` and rename (to `YYYY-MM-DD.csv`) it using your computer's date:

```
Dim sSourceFile
Dim sDestinationFolder
Dim sDate
Dim objFSO

sSourceFile = "I:\This is it\External Storage\Replen\Data\LOCATIONS\ITEM INVENTORY BY PURCHASE ORDER.csv"
sDestinationFolder = "I:\This is it\External Storage\Replen\Data\LOCATIONS\ITEM INVENTORY BY PURCHASE ORDER\"

' Build date string
sDate = Year(Now) & "-" & Month(Now) & "-" & Day(Now)

' Create FileSystem object
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Check if File exists
If objFSO.FileExists(sSourceFile) Then

    ' Move file
    objFSO.Movefile sSourceFile, sDestinationFolder & sDate & ".csv"

Else
    ' File does not exist
End If
```

Comment: That's brilliant! Thank you! would I be able to add time to this as well by adding that to the sDate string?

Comment: Yes, you can use `Hour(Now)` and `Minute(Now)` to do so.